# How to get a collection of files from Windows in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get a collection of children in a Windows folder in my VB program. I don't know what classes / methods to use. I could look it up but I wouldn't know what to search for and .NET has way too much documentation to wade through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static methods in  [Directory class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) and [File class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx) should be all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) method.  This returns an array of strings of all the files found in a given directory:

```
Dim files as string() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\myfiles")
```

Answer (score 1):

DirectoryInfo - the class that has directory information

See example

```
  foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
                     dir.GetFiles
```

FileInfo - class that responsible for file represenattion

Namespace  System.IO must be used

You can use static methods of  File class

```
File.Copy(sourceFileName, tmpFileName, true);
```